# jMeter not able to login to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jmeter

I am trying to create a jMeter test to login to wordpress and post a new blog on a local installation of wordpress.

Recorded wordpress login sequence using the recorder.
Added cookie manager to the test plan.

However I am not able to login to wordpress. I tried all the possible of combination of Cookie policy and Implementation settings for Cookie manager, but it did not help.

When I recorded against the publicly hosted wordpress, the login did not succeed, but the response had an error saying that your browser have not enabled cookies.

I am using jMeter 2.11 on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you provide your plan and also the details for the relevant components, namely your HTTP Cookie Manager and the HTTP Request that performs the login. Please also provide the full error.

Comment: I am also having this issue. I am not able to login to wordpress. I have used the test recorder to record my action but when I replay. It tells me I have disabled cookie in my browser. Can you please shed light on this. 

I did set CookieManager.check.cookies=false and the error is still there. i wonder if you did change some other cookie settings in the jmeter properties file.

Thank you and looking forward to a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [jmeter mailing list post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/201405.mbox/%3CCAHnoMfrziu-7Y9SeK3m=9QAj1FfopCBUhxq8nZhwik6xc-PG2g@mail.gmail.com%3E) I had to set the CookieManager.check.cookies=false  in jmeter.properties. It worked fine with this setting. I am still wondering is wordpress app not complying with standard or what?

Comment: This happens because before saving a Cookie JMeter checks if it is valid or not. My understanding is because the Cookie format is not valid JMeter is not saving. [reference](http://p3lang.com/2016/02/jmeter-wordpress-login-issues/)

Answer (score 0):

using only cookie manager will not be helpful
what I suggest is the following:

- find the dynamic parameters (e.g sessionID) which go along with the Login **POST**   request.
- Use Regex extractor to save those values in a variable.
- pass the variable instead of the value, where ever required.

Links for reference:
https://flood.io/blog/28-guide-to-jmeter-regular-expressions

Hope this will be helpful.